# Comparison Test for Convergence of Improper Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can I determine whether the following improper integrals converge or diverge?

1) $\int_0^\pi \frac{x}{\sin(x)}dx$

2) $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{\cos(x)}}{x}dx$

3) $\int_0^1(\log x)^{\frac{1}{3}}dx$

I have heard of the comparison test, but I am not sure how, if possible, to use it here.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. You may write

1. $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi} \frac{x}{\sin x}dx$

   here the integrand is such that, **for $x$ near $\pi$**, we have

   $$\frac{x}{\sin x} \sim \frac{\pi}{\pi -x}$$

   and your initial integral is divergent.
2. $\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{\cos x}}{x}dx$

   here the integrand is such that, **for $x$ near $0$**, we have

   $$\frac{e^{\cos x}}{x} \sim \frac{1}{x}$$

   and your initial integral is divergent.
3. $\displaystyle \int_0^{1} (-\log x)^{1/3}dx$

   here the change of variable $u=-\log x$ in the integrand gives

   $$\int_0^{1} (-\log x)^{1/3}dx =\int_0^{+\infty} u^{1/3}e^{-u}du\quad(=\Gamma (4/3)),$$

   the initial integral is convergent.

Comment: In the third one, the integrand is $(\log x)^{\frac{1}{3}}$, not $(- \log x)^{\frac{1}{3}}$. Doesn't that change things?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x) = \frac{x}{sin(x)}$ for simplicity.

$1)\ Write: \int_0^{\pi}f(x)dx = \int_0^{\frac\pi2}f(x)dx + \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}f(x)dx$

Now, use $sin(x) \sim x$ in $N(0)$; then, $f(x) \sim 1$ in $N(0)$, so the first integral on the RHS converges.

For the second integral on the RHS, use the change of variable $u = \pi - x$, and find out that the integral diverges.

$2)$ Note that $e^{cos(x)} \ge e^{-1} \ for \ all \ x$. It is easy to use comparison from here.

$3)$ Use the change of variable $u = log(x)$ to see it more clearly. Or simply use the limit test.

Answer (score 0):

For (1), you can use the fact that $\lim_{x \to \pi} (1/(x - \pi))/(1/(\sin ( x - \pi))) \to 1$, which you can show by L'Hoptial's rule, and then do a comparison test from there. For (2), you can put a positive lower bound on $e^{\cos x}$ (which is always positive) and compare the integral to $\int (C/x)  dx$ where $C > 0 $ is the lower bound.

Comment: You may want to use "\frac" command rather than "/" for fractions. See [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more